# I'm not able able access the method of class

Tags: java, android, class, object

I have the class which has to details inside the data http://www.mocky.io/v2/5cacde192f000078003a93bb , i have written a class to get the data and next class to get the details

```
public class ApiObject {


        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        public String status;
        @SerializedName("data")
        @Expose
        public List<MyData> data = null;


        @SerializedName("products")
        public List<Products> products = null;

        public List<MyData> getData() {

                return data;
        }

        public class MyData{
                @SerializedName("details")
                public Details details;
                @SerializedName("product_count")
                public Integer productCount;


                public Details getDetails(){
                        return details;
                }
                @SerializedName("product_count")
                @Expose
                private String Product_count;
                @SerializedName("products")

                public List<Products> getProducts(){
                        return products;
                }
//setter and getters
        }
```

I have created a object of Apiobject in more class
and I'm trying to access the getDetails method

like

```
ApiObject apiObject ;
apiObject.getData().getDetails();
```

I'm getting an error cannot resolve a method

Answer (score 0):

getDetails() is a private method. Therefore, can only be accessed from within the class MyData. Make it public for it to be accessible to instances of other classes.

Comment: The getData() method returns a List of MyData objects, but the getDetails() method returns the Details object of a particular MyData object. It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Either you access one distinct MyData object of the list and then call getDetails() or if you want the details of all MyData objects in the list, you will want to do the same within a for-loop structure, storing the retrieved details in a new list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. getDetails() is a private method, make it public if you want to access it.
2. getData() return a list of MyData objects, not a single instance. So, you should iterate through the list if you want to call the getDetails().

   ```
   for (MyData data : apiObject.getData()) {
       data.getDetails();
   }
   ```